# Will PHP script terminate when I close browser?

Tags: apache

I wrote some web-scraper in PHP.

It needs about 400 seconds to get pages data.

**What will happen, when I close browser before it returns page to browser?**

I tested this few times and it looks like my script reaches its end, but I **will this work always like this?**

Im asking, because I want to run much longer script (that takes 8 hours), and im worried, that there are some circumstances that may terminate my script.

Im using Apache on dedicated server, I don't expect any service restarts or something like this, I have full control on that machine. My max_execution_time is set to 0.

I know, that I should do it some other way (split work to parts, use php.exe from console etc.), but now - im asking about executing PHP script from browser.

Comment: Thanks @ComFreek. Shall I delete this question?

Comment: @Kamil: You could store information about the tasks you want to do in a DB and set up a cronjob to run another PHP script that works off some of these tasks and stores the result again in the DB, so the client doesn't have to keep his tab open. It's called a task queue.

Comment: @Kamil: No, I don't think so. Just leave it open (and accept Patrick Evans' answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when the browser closes or user hits escape it basically ends the script, to keep it going even if these happen use [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

At the top of the script

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```